# Extract year from cognos report expression

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

I want to extract current year, last year in report expression field but am not able to get it.
`date2timestamp(Today())` and `Today()`
This works fine to get date

`_add_years(date2timestamp(Today()),1)` and `extract("year",Today())`
but this shows error.
I wanted to show 2016, 2015 dynamically in my report as heading of cross-tab node.

Answer (score 0):

If you use layout calculation try

```
substring(date2string(Today()),1,4)
```

for current year. And

```
string2int32(substring(date2string(Today()),1,4)) - 1
```

for previous year.

Comment: I'm getting error `RSV-VAL-0002 invalid expression extract(year, current_date). CRX-YXX-4010 a parsing error was found at or near the position 8 in the expression " extract(year, current_date) "`

Comment: Are you using Layout calculation?

Comment: I want to show Crosstab Node Member dynamically.
Thanks for your efforts but still its not working for me :(

Comment: Try Report Studio's built in date current_date

Answer (score 0):

for current year:
`extract('year', date2timestamp(today()))`

for prior year:
`extract('year', _add_years(date2timestamp(today()), -1))`

This will give you an integer value that you can format using the normal *Data Format* options in the date item properties, for example to remove the thousands comma if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Make a query with two data items.

For the previous year, one data item will have:

```
extract (year, _add_years(current_date, -1))
```

And for the current year:

```
extract (year, current_date).
```